# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 component lifecycle hooks

Tags: angular, events, ionic2, hook, lifecycle

I have a component in a page that I need to hook in to every time the page is navigated to. It contains a mapbox map and I'm finding that it's not resizing correctly if a user registers using the register page and pulls up the keyboard and then goes back to the map page the map div is smaller because the user pulled open the keyboard on their phone. I hope this makes sense?

I've tried all the hooks listed here https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks but none of them fire each time the page is navigated to.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Found any success?

Comment: Not yet, might have to use the page event hooks to call a method in the component. Not very clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try: `ionViewDidEnter()`, together with `@ViewChild`. With `@ViewChild` you can access the component.

From Ionic [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/):
"`ionViewDidEnter()` will fire when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page."

Which will give you the possibility to call a function on the component every time the page is navigated to.

**parent-page TS:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-page',
    templateURL: 'parent-page.html'
})
export class ParentPage{
    @ViewChild('myComponent') myComponent;

    constructor(){}

    ionViewDidEnter(){
        this.myComponent.someFunc();
    }

    ...
}
```

**parent-page HTML:**

```
<ion-content>
    ...
    <child-component #myComponent></child-component>
    ...
</ion-content>
```

Comment: ionViewDidEnter only triggers on pages not components? I think I'm going to have to use the page events to call a method in the component?

Comment: A page is a component

Comment: Yer, your not following me maybe? A page is a component BUT a page is an extension of a component and only a page has ionViewDidEnter? components only have these hooks https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. as you can see there is no ionViewDidEnter.

Comment: Thanks for your help @robbannn but ionViewDidEnter does nothing inside the component. It does not fire.

Comment: `ionViewDidEnter(){
  console.log('Hello Home Map Provider, did enter hook');
 }` does not fire in the component :(

Comment: http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/ view child looks like what I'm after maybe? this way I can call a method on the child from the parent page using ionViewDidEnter(). I'll give it a go but it does seem a bit messy? surly there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Yip, viewChild is the way to do it :) thanks for your time bro. have a great day/night.